# Laravel 5.6 store() disk stays the default one

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I used this method before to specify path to my storage folder inside public folder to store images:

```
$file->store('storage/cars/' . $img . 'uploads')
```

And in config/filesystems.php

```
'uploads' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root'   => public_path(),
],
```

It worked before and now even if I add this it uploads to `storage/app/storage/cars` as it's on default.

**ANSWER**

```
$file->store('storage/cars/' . $img , 'uploads')
```

I had dot instead of comma.

This directly uploads to public folder.

Comment: what worked out, what doesn't work now, what problem are you getting, what help do you expect ?

Comment: its always uploading to storage/app directory instead to one I added as new directory for uploads.

Comment: When using the local driver, all file operations are relative to the root directory defined in your configuration file. By default, this value is set to the storage/app directory.

Comment: @Rahi as I added I changed configuration file and still it doesnt work, on prev version it worked just fine.

Comment: Check your .env file as if there is some APP_STORAGE=

Comment: Edited my answer to fit your way of doing it :)

Comment: I found answer `  . 'uploads'` needs to have comma not dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public_path() **outputs storage/app**, thats why after you execute store it will be saved on **storage/app/storage/cars**, so what you want is to specify the path to be just **storage** ->

```
'uploads' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root'   => public_path().'/storage
]
```

Then when you want to save the file you could do this:

```
$file->store('cars/' . $img , 'uploads')
```

Comment: I found answer`  . 'uploads'` needs to have comma not dot.

Comment: weird and you are still using $file->store('storage/cars/' . $img , 'uploads') public_path outputs storage/app doesnt it?

Comment: nop now it works perfect it goes to public directory not storage one, directly

Comment: I can accept your answer I see your point there but it always worked like this for me.

Comment: yeap didn't understand what directory you wanted the file to be because of the weird error caused by the dot X)